# I have a JSON full of the items, and I wanted a way to add the items to the embed page automatically, but instead it spams new embeds for each item

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

My code:

```js
 // Getting My Obj
 const storeOptions = require('../util/storeOption.json')
        const options = Object.keys(storeOptions)
        // Looping through them all
        for (const x of options) {

        const option = {
            name: `${storeOptions[x].emoji} ${storeOptions[x].name}`,
            value: `${storeOptions[x].cost}\n${storeOptions[x].description}`
        }
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()        
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription('Here is our store!\n\n**Shop Items**')
        .addFields(option)
        message.channel.send(embed)
    }
```

I would like all of the fields to be inside of a single embed, but instead it spams new ones, with a single object within the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It spams new embed for each item because you're declaring and sending embed to channel inside for loop.
Also, you're using `addFeilds` that you can use to set multiple feilds at once by providing array of objects(with name & value) at once. [Check this for reference](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)

What I suggest is that you declare `MessageEmbed` before for loop and `addFeild` to the embed on each iteration .

```js
const storeOptions = require('../util/storeOption.json')
const options = Object.keys(storeOptions)

// Declare embed before for loop starts
const embed = new MessageEmbed() 
        .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription('Here is our store!\n\n**Shop Items**')

for (const x of options) {
    const option = {
        name: `${storeOptions[x].emoji} ${storeOptions[x].name}`,
        value: `${storeOptions[x].cost}\n${storeOptions[x].description}`
    }
    // Add Feild to embed
    embed.addField(option)
}

return message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Only problem, `embed.addField` does not take in an object, it takes in a string.
However, `embed.addFields` does work, since it takes in an object.

Comment: Ohk.. thanks for letting me know, I left the object as it is so that It'll be easy to understand as you were doing it this way in your code.